# Unix uniq -c to csv format

Tags: unix

I'm trying to get a uniq -c output like the following:

```
100 a
99 b
45 c
etc...
```

To write to a file in csv format using only unix utils, with the ordering reversed:

```
a,100
b,99
c,45
etc...
```

I figure I can pipe the output into `tr " " ","` to get the csv format, but how do I get the order of the columns to be reversed, only using unix utils?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat test.txt | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Comment: This seems to add a `^M` character between the two arguments: `a^M 100` do you know how to get rid of this?

Comment: then, check your origin data, there must be a `^M` after your first column.

Comment: it's a control character, your can  treat it like a normal string using `sed 's/^M//g'` be aware that the `^M` should be input with  a sequence of keyborad input Ctrl+v Ctrl+m  in a console or vim

Comment: Hmm it seems like this is the desired line terminator in the spec, so thats why awk is putting it in the middle there. Is there some way to keep that at the end i.e. `a 100^M` ?

Comment: quick thought `cat test.txt | sed 's/^M//g' | awk '{print $2,$1"^M"}'` `^M` should be input as above post mentioned.

Comment: If you want to skip the trip to `tr`, Awk can be told to change its output field separator as well: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {print $2,$1}'` will ensure that your fields are delimited with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

armnotstrong's is probably the simplest but you can also use `sed`

```
sed -r 's/(.+) (.+)/\2,\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

For these one liners in unix, i like to use perl.

```
uniq -c yourfile | perl -lne 's/^(\s*)(\d*)(\s*)(.*)/$4,$2/g; print $_'
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference is how the "," gets included in the output. If done as per @armnotstrong, the result will just be a bunch of lines seperated by spaces.

`bash
=> cat text
100 a
99 b
98 c
=> cat text | awk '{print $2","$1}'
a,100
b,99
c,98`

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` solutions don't work correctly if your text data contains spaces.

Based on @cbreezier's answer, I came up with this solution:

```
sed -r 's/ +([0-9]+) (.+)/\2,\1/'
```